# Short Pikachu graph

Tags: graphing-functions

What is the shortest way to make parametric formula(s) that makes a Pikachu? I've seen many formulas on Wolfram Alpha and others but most seem to be either really long or consists of multiple formulas.

For those people who don't know what Pikachu is ( who doesn't) this is him. [image: Pikachu!]

I am looking for the basic outline and maybe a few details, but nothing in particular.

Maybe something like this:

[image]

What is a good example in the form of $X_t,Y_t$?

Comment: First of all, come out of your fantasy land. Second of all, no function in single variable can have two values for a single pre - image. So i don't think this is possible by "single function"

Comment: @TheDeadLegend , thanks for telling me to grow up. But I don't need to be told. There is plenty of growing up for me in the next $3*2$ years. An you don't even know how old I am!!

Comment: Lol, no one said about growing up xD. I just begged you to halt your search for a single variable function which will satisfy your pickachu ambtions. (I'm a charlizard fan though :p)

Comment: Use spline approximations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Desmos uses only 56 curves.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/i2yvtbufgv)
However, in order to be more efficient and make a graphed version of Pikachu resemble the original Pikachu as animated in the series or those that appear as [sprites in the games](https://pokemondb.net/sprites/pikachu), multiple curves need to be necessarily used.

What's the shortest Pikachu graph? The one on [WA uses only 2 parametric functions!](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pikachu+curve) (Granted,the functions themselves are beasts composed of tons of added trig functions.)

---

Essentially, a very short set of equations describing pikachu would simply be of a lesser quality, i.e. it'll create a pikachu which wouldn't exactly BE a pikachu.